# How to pass objects to keywords in robot framework?

Tags: python, object, robotframework, method-call

I have a python class `MyClass` written in file `MyClass.py`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = list()

    def setvar(self, val):
        self.myvar = val

    def mymethod(self):
        return self.myvar
```

I have imported in Robot Framework as below:

```
Library         MyClass    WITH NAME    my_component
```

I also have a keyword which call a method of objects which are passed to it:

```
testing component
    [Arguments]       ${cmp}
    log to console    ************* ${cmp}
    ${result} =       ${cmp}.mymethod
```

I have multiple objects instantiated from class `MyClass` and every object has different properties. I want to get their attributes using `testing component` keyword regardless of the object itself.

When I call `testing component` passing `my_component`:

```
Test Method Call
    testing component    my_component
```

I get:

```
No keyword with name '${cmp}.mymethod' found.
```

If I call it this way in keyword `testing component`:

```
${result} =    call method     ${cmp}   mymethod
```

I get:

```
Object 'my_component' does not have method 'mymethod'.
```

I also tried `call method     my_component    mymethod` for test and I again got `Object 'my_component' does not have method 'mymethod'.`.

But when I use `${result} =     my_component.mymethod`, everything works fine.

Comment: Does `MyClass.py` define a class named `MyClass`?  Or is `MyClass.py` a simple module with functions?

Comment: @BryanOakley please review my edit on the question

Answer (score 6):

The literal answer to your question of how to call a method of a python object is that you can use extended variable syntax (eg: `${cmp.mymethod()}` or you can use the `call method` keyword (eg: `call method    ${cmp}    mymethod`).

For example, normal scalar variables in robot are python string objects. Thus, we can call methods on them such as `lower()` and `upper()`. The following test case shows how you can call these methods on a string, using the two mechanisms I mentioned earlier:

```
*** Variables ***
${message}    Hello, world    # a python string object

*** Test cases ***
Example
    # Example using "Call method" keyword
    ${lower}=    call method    ${message}    lower
    should be equal    ${lower}    hello, world

    # Example using extended variable syntax
    ${upper}=    set variable    ${message.upper()}
    should be equal    ${upper}    HELLO, WORLD
```

The problem with your code is your misunderstanding of what `my_component` and `${cmp}` represents. They are *not* python objects. Rather, it is the *name* of a robot framework library. Even though under the hood it may exist as a reference to an instance of a class defined in the library, from within the test `my_component` is simply the *name* of the library.

This is why `my_component.my_method` works - `my_component` is the name of a library, and `my_method` is the name of a keyword within that library. This is standard robot framework syntax. See [Specifying a keyword explicitly](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#specifying-a-keyword-explicitly) in the robot framework user guide.

If you want to be able to pass `my_component` around as if it were an object, you can use `run keyword` to run the keywords implemented in that library.

For example, start by creating `MyClass.py` with the following code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def mymethod(self):
        return "Hello, world"
```

Your code can work if you replace `call method` with `run keyword`:

```
*** Keywords ***
testing component
    [Arguments]       ${cmp}
    log to console    ************* ${cmp}
    ${result} =       run keyword   ${cmp}.mymethod
```

Finally, if you really want to pass the actual library *object* around, you can use the built-in keyword [Get Library Instance](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance) to get the actual library object, which you can then use with [Call Method](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Call%20Method)

```
*** Keywords ***
testing component
    [Arguments]       ${cmp_name}
    ${cmp}=  Get library instance    ${cmp_name}
    log to console    ************* ${cmp}
    ${result} =       call method    ${cmp}    mymethod
    [return]          ${result}
```

Oddly, the extended variable syntax doesn't work in this case. I don't know why.